# Django - Mocking the save method on a model

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I'm still here with my beginner questions about Django unit tests ^^

I'm trying to test that the save function of a model was called, without actually call the save.

Here is the method i want to test :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import models as auth_model
from allauth.socialaccount import models as allauth_model

class KangaUserManager(models.Manager):
    def create(self, username, email, password, last_name, first_name, request, registered=True, send_confirmation=True):
        kanga_user = KangaUser()
        kanga_user.user = auth_model.User.objects.create_user(
            username=username,
            email=email,
            password=password,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name
        )
        kanga_user.preferred_language = translation.get_language()
        kanga_user.registered = registered
        kanga_user.save()

        return kanga_user
```

Here is the test

```
@mock.patch('model.models.KangaUser')
@mock.patch('django.contrib.auth.models.User')
def test_create(self, UserMock, KangaUserMock):
    # Mocking configuration
    # User
    UserMock.objects = mock.MagicMock()
    UserMock.objects.create_user = mock.MagicMock()
    user_return_value = User(id=1)
    UserMock.objects.create_user.return_value = user_return_value

     # Test
    kangauser_manager = models.KangaUserManager()
    kanga_user = kangauser_manager.create(self.username, self.email, self.password, self.last_name, self.first_name, self.request, self.registered, self.send_confirmation)

    # Checks
    # create_user called with good parameters
    UserMock.objects.create_user.assert_called_with(username=self.username, email=self.email, password=self.password, first_name=self.first_name, last_name=self.last_name)
    # KangaUser 
    self.assertTrue(models.KangaUser.save.called)
```

The first test (UserMock.objects.create_user.assert_called_with) is ok, but for the second, I always end up having "AssertionError: False is not true"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After some more googling, I found something that works :

```
@mock.patch.object(models.KangaUser, 'save')
@mock.patch('django.contrib.auth.models.User')
def test_create(self, user_class_mock, kangauser_save_mock):
    # Mocking configuration
    # User
    user_class_mock.objects = mock.MagicMock()
    user_class_mock.objects.create_user = mock.MagicMock()
    user_class_mock.objects.create_user.return_value = User(id=1)

    # Test
    kangauser_manager = models.KangaUserManager()
    kanga_user = kangauser_manager.create(self.username, self.email, self.password, self.last_name, self.first_name, self.request, self.registered, self.send_confirmation)

    # Checks
    # create_user called with good parameters
    user_class_mock.objects.create_user.assert_called_with(username=self.username, email=self.email, password=self.password, first_name=self.first_name, last_name=self.last_name)
    # KangaUser 
    self.assertTrue(kangauser_save_mock.called)
```

So, the trick was to use @mock.patch.object !

Comment: Would you mind sharing what kind of code you used for `kangauser_save_mock`? I would like to sure that the super `.save` method is called after the mock is done.

Comment: There is no code behind it, it's a mock. It is defined with the @mock.patch.object(models.KangaUser, 'save') annotation of the method.

Answer (score 0):

With [pytest-mock](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/) you can do:

```py
def test_create(self, mocker):
    mocker.patch("path_to_the_kanga_user_manager.KangaUser.save")
```

Answer (score 0):

@CBrunain's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27668275) got me started on the right path, particularly with `mock.patch.object(models.KangaUser, 'save')`. In my case, however, my unit test still needed `Model.save` to function how it's supposed to.

I ended up finding the [`wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock) parameter:

> wraps: Item for the mock object to wrap. If wraps is not None then
> calling the Mock will pass the call through to the wrapped object
> (returning the real result). Attribute access on the mock will return
> a Mock object that wraps the corresponding attribute of the wrapped
> object (so attempting to access an attribute that doesn’t exist will
> raise an AttributeError).

In other words, you can mock `save` without overriding its functionality just for the purpose of checking how many times it's been called:
`@mock.patch.object(models.KangaUser, 'save', wraps=models.KangaUser.save)`

To give the full answer, the code below is the same as @CBrunain's but with the adjusted mock and an additional `Mock.call_count` example:

```
@mock.patch.object(models.KangaUser, 'save', wraps=models.KangaUser.save)
@mock.patch('django.contrib.auth.models.User')
def test_create(self, user_class_mock, kangauser_save_mock):
    # Mocking configuration
    # User
    user_class_mock.objects = mock.MagicMock()
    user_class_mock.objects.create_user = mock.MagicMock()
    user_class_mock.objects.create_user.return_value = User(id=1)

    # Test
    kangauser_manager = models.KangaUserManager()
    kanga_user = kangauser_manager.create(self.username, self.email, self.password, self.last_name, self.first_name, self.request, self.registered, self.send_confirmation)

    # Checks
    # create_user called with good parameters
    user_class_mock.objects.create_user.assert_called_with(username=self.username, email=self.email, password=self.password, first_name=self.first_name, last_name=self.last_name)
    # KangaUser 
    self.assertTrue(kangauser_save_mock.called)

    self.assertEqual(1, kangauser_save_mock.call_count)
```

Comment: Interresting ! In my case I wanted to be completely separate from the database, so no real calls, but it can comes handy !